# download file currently being written via python

Tags: python, download, bittorrent

Okay, this is not exactly a python problem(yet), but it is a problem , and I would prefer to use python for any code work that goes into the solution.

**Scenario:**

I have a vps with a killer internet connection. I can use it to torrent large files with not too many seeds. My local connection is ~1mbps, but somehow for these badly seeded torrents, I get around 30-40% of my speed max(average 15kBps). I have noticed that even on these poor torrents , the vps does far better. So far I have been torrenting these to the vps(at 10mbps+)and then using apache to host them and http download them on to my local machine at 100% of my local internet speed. Overall transfer time reduces by a LOT.

**Problem:**

As is obvious at this point, I wait for the file to get downloaded to the vps first and then download from vps to local machine. I don't like that one bit. So I want to start transferring to local machine as soon as vps starts downloading(streaming sort of, but saved to a file). Ideally I would like to automate the entire process.. so that final solution script would just take a torrent file and local destination directory as inputs and save the file to my local machine(the script would handle ssh and everything). But partial solutions are okay too(as in not complete automation) as long as I don't have to wait for the file to get downloaded at the vps first to start transfer to local machine.

**VPS:**

Debian,rtorrent,apache

**Local machine:**

windows 7, python 2.7
(I am currently downloading via free download manager and I have automated that via python before.. but other ideas are invited, as long as it lets me stop and resume if I want)

Note that I am not looking for code, just a plan on how to achieve the goal(s).
Hope someone helps.

Comment: Won't work, since bittorrent doesn't work that way. Unless you'd push completed chunks into some queue and assemble them at the local machine, which would require quite a lot of patching a BT client.

Comment: Skip the apache/http download. Just have start your local and VPS bittorrent clients simultaneously. Your VPS should get added to the pool of peers, and your client download speed should jump up to 1M.